# Linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ with two vectors and finding a result

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

My title is bad but I'm not quite sure how to ask this in English as it is not my first language.

I have a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ with vectors $x = (4,6,2)$ which in $T(x) = (8,10,4)$ and vector $y = (2,2,4)$ which in $T(y) = (6,-2,4)$. Find $T(2,6,-8)$.

I know how to do this with three vectors, but its strange that I can't seem to figure out with two vectors. Should the third vector I use be some result through the use of vectors x and y?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $(2, 6, -8) = 2 \cdot (4, 6, 2) - 3 \cdot (2, 2, 4)$.